# QT 6.6.0. C++ camera issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt, camera, 64-bit

I am new to QT and I can't figure out why my code is not working. It does not matter whether the camera is connected to the PC or not, my app crashes. The crash is probably caused by `m_captureSession` related code lines in `mainwindow.cpp`.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QScopedPointer<QCamera> m_camera;
    QScopedPointer<QMediaCaptureSession> m_captureSession;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_camera.reset(new QCamera(QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput()));
    m_captureSession->setCamera(m_camera.data());
    m_captureSession->setVideoOutput(ui->cameraViewfinder);
    m_camera->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Camera permission is granted and the QCamera object successfully connects to my device

Comment: `QCamera camera(QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput());` this is a local variable in the constructor. It no longer exists after the constructor is finished. Same with `QMediaCaptureSession captureSession;`

Comment: @drescherjm I updated my code. Now it crashes

Comment: With the new code you forgot to allocate the `m_captureSession` so `m_captureSession->setCamera(m_camera.data());` is dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The solution in my case was giving up the idea of using  `QScopedPointer` for `QMediaCaptureSession`. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: You can also use a normal  raw pointer and set the parent to the `MainWindow`. That way when the `MainWindow` is destroyed all its child objects are destroyed.